# Using script via custom menu to one-click refresh formulas in cells rather than clicking into cells individually to refresh formulas in cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently, I have to keep clicking into individual cells with `=query()` formulas to refresh the cells' formulas when I import a new datasheet into the template sheet.

How this is supposed to work is that users make a copy of the template sheet every time and import a new datasheet with values that will be reflected in cells A2 and B2 on the "report overview" tab of the template copy.

Instead of clicking into individual cells with `#REF!` to "activate"/"refresh" the formula in those cells, is there a script that can be used with a custom menu so that users just have to click on a menu button and have specific cells like A2 and B2 be "refreshed" altogether.

Template (Google Sheets) - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11JZMo-cgTCTPx9U6SYwDX7L26kpsQ5YDQH-IuW_3TY8

Datasheet (.xlsx/.xls) - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IprKWqX1OolT1k6x3OClFjMOHd1LIpsc

Comment: How is the data from the new datasheet imported?

Comment: You just need to `getFormulas` and `setFormulas` to the same range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any script ...

- add a tab and a checkbox in A1
- in B2 `=iferror(QUERY(indirect("Pets!A2:D11"),"SELECT A WHERE B>5"),refresh!$A$1)`
- in C2 `=iferror(QUERY(indirect("Pets!A2:D11"),"SELECT C WHERE D>5"),refresh!$A$1)`

to activate all formulas evrywhere, check/unchek the box in A1*

you can also do that by a simple script

```
function refresh() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('refresh')
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue(!sh.getRange('A1').getValue())
}
```

edit : the basic method by script is to clear the cells and then re-build by script the formulas

Comment: Hi @Mike! Unfortunately, there can't be any addition of cells in the template.

Comment: Put the checkbox in another tab?

Comment: any other methods besides requiring an additional cell/tab in the template?

Comment: the basic method by script is to clear the cells and then re-build by script the formulas

Answer (score 1):

Add this as a script:

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Refresh Formulae").addItem("Refresh", "refresh").addToUi()
}

function refresh() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("report overview")
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:B2")
  
  range.setFormulas(range.getFormulas())
}
```

Rundown:

- On open, create a menu item to refresh the formulae
- Once authorised and run, this will re-set the formulae in A2 and B2

#### References:

- [`getFormulas()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas())
- [`setFormulas()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormulas())

Comment: Note: This won't work if your formulae aren't set correctly and have `#REF`s in them so make sure they are set correctly